# Regex formula for `**abc_abc**` from string `**abc_abc** abc abc **abc_abc** in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have multiple strings, in some cases the string is `**abc_abc**` and in some it is `**abc_abc** abc abc abc **abc_abc**` I only need to pick out a single pair of "**" (so `**abc_abc**`). I have been using regex till now that seemed to be working fine but I just spotted that on the second example it picks up the whole thing.

my regex till now has been:

```
\\*\\*(.*?)_(.*?)\\*\\*
```

any idea on how to get only that single pair of stars?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is no problem with the string you posted, but you probably need `\\*\\*((?:(?!\\*\\*)[^_])*)_(.*?)\\*\\*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ws1DDj/1))

Comment: Yes! Dziekuje! If you want to submit your comment as an answer I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid matching strings starting from "non-qualifying" `**...**` you need to temper the first group with a more specific pattern:

```java
\*\*((?:(?!\*\*)[^_])*)_(.*?)\*\*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ws1DDj/1). *Details*:

- `\*\*` - a `**` string
- `((?:(?!\*\*)[^_])*)` - Capturing group 1: any char but `_` that does not start a `**` substring, zero or more times, as many as possible
- `_` - a `_` char
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\*\*` - a `**` string

Java regex declaration:

```java
String regex = "\\*\\*((?:(?!\\*\\*)[^_])*)_(.*?)\\*\\*";
```